# How many RDS CAL licenses do I need?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, licensing, rds, microsoft

I have 1 server with OS Windows Server 2012R2 where I need to install Remote Desktop Services role. I know that without RDS CAL I can connect to this server via RDP 2 users but what when I need to connect 10 users?
Do I have to buy all 10 CALs or maybe buy only 8 CALs and link them with 2 already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two "built in" licenses are for administration of the server. They may not be used in the way you intend your users to use the server. You need to purchase 10 RDS CAL's.